# Paper that acknowledges something

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a particular word in English language. What do you call a paper which acknowledges something?

For example, at university when you ask for a list of passed exams (be it a analog or digital), you get a signed document. What is the name of such type of document?

I found the word “approbation” but I am uncertain about validity for this case.

Comment: _Approbation_ certainly isn't what you want.  There's probably no one word that covers _all_ uses for what I think you're asking (your question is possibly too broad without going into more detail). _Certificate_ could work for exams, so start by looking for synonyms of that.

Comment: Ah, alright, at least I now know approbation is not the right now. The “certificate” seems too specific for actually passing some exam - you need to give some answers which are being evaluated and you are are given certificate, optionally, based on that.

Comment: No single word except maybe *document,*, but certificate of attendance and certificate of course completion.are often used for this purpose.

Comment: I think you are looking for *transcript* - an official record of a student's work, showing courses taken and grades achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Attestation.

Dutch actually has a word for this: "attest". It's somewhat like a certificate, but broader. As a native Dutch speaker, I've seen it used for any document that bears any form of proof. Whether it's a certificate (for finishing a course/class/curriculum), an authentication (e.g. a proof of no criminal record), official documentation (e.g. your car's registration), a doctor's note or a permission slip; "attest" applies to all of them.

[The Dutch dictionary](http://www.woorden.org/woord/attest) describes "attest" as:

> A written declaration that serves as evidence.

Which is what you're after. Sadly, I can't think of any direct synonym in English that covers all use cases.

However, the verb "to attest" comes pretty close in meaning:

> [**To attest**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attest)
>   *verb*
>
> - Provide or serve as clear evidence of.
>
>   - Declare that something exists or is the case.
>   - Witness or certify formally.

And this meaning seems to be preserved in the noun [**attestation**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/attestation):

> 1. A thing that serves to bear witness, confirm or authenticate.
> 2. A confirmation or authentication.

Althought an attestation is not necessarily a physical document, I see a reasonable argument for considering such an implication to be acceptable. The first definition specifically refers to **a thing**, which puts it in a stark contrast to e.g. a verbal testimony.

---

### Alternatives.

I came across some other nouns that are close in meaning, but most of them only cover part of your (broader) definition.

> - **Authentication** => Only applies to documents that verify the validity of a source, which is not always relevant in your case.
> - **Affidavit** => Only applies in a legal context, which is too restrictive.
> - **Declaration** => Only applies if it's a document that bears someone's testimony, not when the document is listing observable facts.
> - **Verification** => Broader than an authentication, and I nearly wanted to suggest this as the correct answer. However, [its listed definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verification) all refer to the **act** of verifying (other sources also include the **state** of being verified), rather than a document.
> - **Confirmation** => Too broad. I see no way to imply that it's a physcial document without making it sound stilted (e.g. "confirmation document").

All these words are partially correct. None of them fully cover the broad definition that you are after, but I do expect that a significant amount of use cases for your broader definition can be accurately described by using one of these nouns.

---

### Verification?

Looking further into it, it seems that the definition of **verification** (in reference to a document) is dependent on which source you follow.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verification) does actually list the definition we're after:

> 3. evidence that establishes or confirms the accuracy or truth of something
>      *We could find no verification for his fantastic claims.*

But [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verification), the [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verification) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verification) do not list a similar definition.

From what I understand, not everyone on English.SE considers Dictionary.com an authoritative source, so whether or not you consider **verification** to be correct is up to you.

Comment: Wow, this is very thorough breakdown of suggestions! Thanks a lot! Looking thought the list, the `attestation` seems to be well fitting, then `certificate`. I cannot exclude the simple `transcript`, suggested by Phil in a comment section.

Comment: 'Verification' as defined even by Wiktionary seems an abstract rather than a concrete usage.